# How to authenticate a local xampp server to send email

Tags: email, authentication, xampp

I once used int_set to send email from my company local xammp server for testing.

```
 ini_set('SMTP','mail.companysite.com');
 ini_set('smtp_port','26');
 ini_set('sendmail_from','email@companysite.com');
```

Now our host has upgraded the server and we have to authenticate email sending. However I have not been able to get ini_set to work with authentication for email. How can this be done?
We are using xampp on windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out:

here is my code:

```
    ini_set('SMTP','mail.somewebsite');
ini_set('smtp_port','26');
ini_set('sendmail_from','email@somewebsite');
ini_set('auth_username','email@somewebsite');
ini_set('auth_password','password');

$headers = "From:email@somewebsite\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
"MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n";


mail("email@gmail.com", "testing authentication", "hello world", $headers);
```